# Using the law of independent assortment, why can't heterozygous parents make identical twins?

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, reproduction, gene, twins

In a case where two parents are heterozygous, why can't any pairs of their children be identical twins? As the question asks, I tried to explain this using the law of independent assortment, which states that alleles a gamete receives for one gene do not affect alleles for the other. I don't get how this relates to identical twins. When I searched this up, I found that identical twins come from when an egg splits into two, but if it's one cell, why would the law of independent assortment matter? Same with the heterozygous part - why would that affect the formation of identical twins when it's copies of the same cell? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: They do it all the time, because identical twins come from one (fertilized) zygote splits into two embryos instead of remaining one. You and I understand this, but I don't understand the rest of your question. The independent assortment already happened before that split. :/

Comment: what do you mean when you "heterozygous" exactly? all humans are heterozygous (or rather, the probability of complete homozygosity of a human genome created by sex is astronomically small)

Comment: Are you sure the question is about twins? or just identical children from separate gestations? If the latter - then you can explain it using independent assortment. The former - as already mentioned - happens all the time for reasons already explained.